# How to redirect to desired URL after Azure ActiveDirectory Login-Callback

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, blazor, blazor-webassembly

The azure AD callback is hard coded to /https://whateversite/authentication/login-callback

This ends up just redirecting the user back to the index page.  How can I either pass extra parameters to AD to include additional redirect details OR maintain some sort of page state to use instead.